# jQuery and jsTree - Check (uncheck) Disable / Remove / Invisible Nodes

Tags: jquery, hidden, jstree, visible

Any one know of a way to only select visible nodes / children not those that are hidden & unchecked. For example

```
[x] Parent
    [x] Child - Visible / checked
    [x] Child - Visible /checked
    [ ] Child - hidden / unchecked - even possible to be checked due to parent
    [ ] Child - hidden / unchecked
```

If you check or uncheck the [x] Parent it checks / unchecked ALL children (visible and hidden). I only want it to check / uncheck (i.e. change the state of) those that are visible and NOT hidden.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was a jQuery one. I gave each node on construction (in php) a class 'aNode' and 'selectable' (if visible) then iterate through all children as followed

```
$.each($('#mytree.jstree-checked'), function(i, v){

    if($(v).hasClass('aNode')){
        if($(v).hasClass('selectable')){

            //found a node that is both selectable (not hidden) and checked
        }
    }
});
```